# Possessive followed by negative gerund

Tags: possessives, negation, gerunds

Is it correct to say this?

> Her not paying attention to the class annoys me.

Comment: Yes, this is 100% correct. And welcome to the site!

Comment: Gerunds, whether negative or not, can have subjects that are either in possessive form (_her, his, Mary's_) or objective (_her, him, Mary_). _Her_ could, of course, be either one, but since they're both correct, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct to have such a **possessive structure** as a **subject**:

> [The Other Side of the Couch: The Healing Bond in Psychiatry](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MB8d9yI3VI8C&pg=PT137&dq=%22Her%20not%20leaving%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UnI1Vd-KJsSBygSIzIHQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Her%20not%20leaving%22&f=false) Gail
>   Albert - 2011
>
> Meanwhile she's already called back twice. **Her not leaving a last
>   name** suggests that she believes I know her when I don't. And the
>   number of calls suggests that she feels I'm a very important—and
>   powerful—figure in her life.